# How to start activity based on listview item click?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onclick

I have the following code but I have tried for days now and I cannot seem to figure out how to start an activity based on the listview item clicked, the result[position] does not work for start intent.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
    holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

EDIT : If the first list item is clicked I want it to start an activity (images class) , if second clicked to start images2 class and so on..

Comment: And have you tried to put an `Intent` on it? Like `Intent intent = new Intent(convertView.getContext(), ActivityUwant.class);
        startActivity(intent);` if it doesn't work try your rowView.getContext();

Comment: Your class it's called Images2, Images3, Images4, etc?

Comment: @Skizo yea , a class to show information on each product.

Comment: Ok, I'm working on your question, give me 5 min :)

Comment: @Skizo Much appreciated :)

Comment: list items position start from 0 so you may need to rename the Activvties to images0, images1 etc, you can probably start the intent like (images+"+position+".class) or (images+position.class)) and your onclick listener goes in the main activity like the last answer below

Comment: @ChadPrecilla check my answer :D

Comment: @Tasos you need to create a String to do it, you can't do this autommatically, like my answer

Comment: @ Skizo -- You mean the Position is an Integer  and you cant concatenate that to images.cllass.? can you do this (String pos  = String.valueOf(position);) and then (images+pos.class))? it will be less code i think but can you concatenate to that?

Comment: @Skizo Cannot stress how grateful I am right now. Worked on the first try thank you soo much :D

Comment: @ChadPrecilla Don't forget to mark it as a correct if I helped you :)

Comment: @Tasos Check my edit, it's how you can call a class from a String

Comment: @Skizo -- cool  thanks, i just saw that update

Comment: @Tasos You're welcome, we are here to learn ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityYouWantToGo.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
         Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

### EDIT

Just create this method on your `BaseAdapter`

```
public void StartActivityForImages(Context context, int i){

    switch (i){
        case 0:
            Intent Intent = new Intent(context, Image0.class);
            context.startActivity(Intent);
            break;

        case 1:
            Intent Intent2 = new Intent(context, Image1.class);
            context.startActivity(Intent2);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent Intent3 = new Intent(context, Image3.class);
            context.startActivity(Intent3);
            break;

        ......
    }

}
```

And on your `setOnClickListener()`

You call this method as follows :

```
 StartActivityForImages(v.getContext(),position);
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

### **Efficient way to do it**

If you don't want to create a method and do this stuff, you could do something like this :

Create a String with the name of your next class like :

```
String NextActivity = getPackageName()+".Image"+position;
```

And then you can do something like this :

```
try {
      String className =getPackageName()+".Image"+2;
      Intent openNewIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Class.forName( className ) );
      startActivity(  openNewIntent );
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         Log.d("ERRORPEW", e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: @ChadPrecilla Wait I've to update something... with the other option

Comment: @ChadPrecilla Done, with this you can avoid the method :P

Comment: Thanks for showing me that way aswell, the method will do just fine tho :D

Comment: @ChadPrecilla You have to mark my answer as a correct (the green check image)

Answer (score 2):

Starting an activity based on a ListView's item click is not done in the adapter. It is done in the Activity where you show the ListView:

**In your Activity:**

```
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter); //mAdapter is your CustomAdapter 
mListView.setClickable(true);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Start the activity here.
        //based on the value of position or id.
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP is trying to start the images activities based on the item position. If he renames them to images0, 1, 2 etc can he start them this way (images+"+position+".class) or (images+position.class)) ? can you concatenate there or convert the position to String and then concatenate?

Comment: @Tasos He does NOT need to. He is already passing the images to his CustomAdapter (See `prgmImages` in the constructor). Which means he has them in his Activity.

Comment: @ iturki -- ok i thought he wanted to start different images activities based on the the item he clicked, that's what question is saying right?

Comment: Yes, thats what the question is saying. What I meant is, in his Activity, he has access to the images and to the ListView items click event. So he can start different images activities.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in onclick

```
    if(position ==1){
    --fire your first intent here.--
    } else if(position ==2) {
    -------your other intent------
    } 
    ----etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make **position** as a final static parameter in getView(), its a wronge way. Use below getView method to startActivity from list Item,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
    holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    rowView.setTag(position);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag;
            Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```